# Exclude system paths from django_coverage

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd, django-apps

I'm running django_coverage over a project with the command `test_coverage`. It's working, but it's including in the output and final calculation code in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages`. I'm not interested in knowing about the coverage of those modules, only the test coverage for my project. I see in the [django_coverage documentation on BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-coverage/src/tip/django_coverage/settings.py) that there is a `COVERAGE_PATH_EXCLUDES`, but that seems to apply only to subdirectories of the project and not absolute system paths. Also, I see that the default for `COVERAGE_MODULE_EXCLUDES` is to exclude any imports with "django" in it, but I'm still getting output for `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django`.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have 'django' listed in COVERAGE_PATH_EXCLUDES? I have a similar setup (django 1.1.2, python 2.6) don't see the output for any django packages in my test coverage results. Can you post what you are using for the excludes?

Comment: In my settings file I have `COVERAGE_PATH_EXCLUDES = ('django',)`.

Comment: Sorry, wrong variable. Look at COVERAGE_MODULE_EXCLUDES. Here is what I'm using,    
    COVERAGE_MODULE_EXCLUDES = [
        'tests$', 
        'settings$',
        'urls$', 
        'common.views.test',
        '__init__', 
        'django'
    ]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not using django so I can't confirm this, but is it possible that you have modified the original code settings file rather than including the settings in your own as it says in step 3 (from the readme excerpt below):

> ### Install as a Django app
>
> 1. Place the entire `django_coverage` app in your third-party apps    directory.
> 2. Update your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` to include `django_coverage`.
> 3. Include test coverage specific settings in your own settings file.    See `settings.py` for more detail.

Comment: This question is not about how to install django coverage but to include/exclude specific application for test.

Comment: @sharafjaffri Wow this is old and I don't remember the details. However I wasn't explaining how to install it but where exupero might have gone wrong when modifying settings for django_coverage.